# Google maps API is returning ZERO_RESULTS for a directions request via API, but works on Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-directions-api

Problematic call in question is:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=35.73455050,-95.31531510&destination=29.67404860,-95.54087240&waypoints=29.92853940,-95.29782860|29.61621200,-95.31759150&mode=driving&key=[API_KEY]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=35.73455050,-95.31531510&destination=29.67404860,-95.54087240&waypoints=29.92853940,-95.29782860%7C29.61621200,-95.31759150&mode=driving&key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D)

Which returns:

```
{
  "available_travel_modes": [
    "DRIVING",
    "WALKING",
    "BICYCLING"
],
"geocoded_waypoints": [
   {},
   {},
   {},
   {}
 ],
  "routes" : [],
  "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

I have read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46061400/11603961) that if you use `via:` on your waypoints, some maneuvers like a U-turn is not allowed. When you display my trip on the Google maps, there is one U-turn and if I slightly change the waypoint in order to remove that U-turn then I get valid results from the API call. I'm confused as to why my request is failing due to a U-turn even if I'm not using `via:` for waypoints.

My question would be how to be able to support routes that may include U-turns?

Note: Thousands of other calls are working as they should, no rate limiting is in place, this is an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same request also [cannot find a route on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/35.7345505,-95.3153151/29.9285394,-95.2978286/29.616212,-95.3175915/29.6740486,-95.5408724/@32.6477386,-98.0599743,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!4m1!3e0?entry=ttu).

The problematic location is 29.92853940,-95.29782860 and the problem is that the closest road segment to that location (29.928413,-95.297976) is a one-way segment.

The **closest** road segment is often not the desired one for routing, which is why the best approach to *reliably* obtain the best available directions from the Directions API (and Routes API, and even Google Maps using [Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#directions-action)) is to specify waypoints as [**Place ID**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id), e.g.

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=35.73455050,-95.31531510&destination=29.67404860,-95.54087240&waypoints=place_id:ChIJrRBC-DqxQIYRG8Pa87ipZ3M|29.61621200,-95.31759150&mode=driving](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=35.73455050,-95.31531510&destination=29.67404860,-95.54087240&waypoints=place_id:ChIJrRBC-DqxQIYRG8Pa87ipZ3M%7C29.61621200,-95.31759150&mode=driving)

Comment: This is precisely what I was doing wrong, once I've resorted to using placeId instead of lat long coordinates my route is being calculated correctly. Much appreciated!